# Insert that retrieves data from a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I am creating a stored procedure to insert data into a table. The table has 8 fields. Five of them are inputs and the other three need to be retrieved from a query that depends on the first five. 
Before the begin statement, i would like to create a temp_table (because it will only take one query to get the rest of the data) and in the VALUES( select col1 from #temp_table, select col2 from #temp_table ...).
Really need some help with the syntax and order.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.table
     @ value1 int,
     @ value2 int, ...etc
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  IF object_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') is not null drop table #temp_table
  SELECT some stuff 
  INTO #temp_table 
  FROM some place
  WHERE magical things happen...
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.table
   ( fields )
   VALUES 
   (
      select colum1 from #temp_table
      etc
   )
END
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
INSERT INTO Tab (col1, col2,....., col8)
SELECT @var1, @var2, ...., var5, t2.val1, t2.val2, t2.val3
FROM Tab2 t2
WHERE (/*you can do your filtering here*/)
```

Comment: @uset2989408 yes: procedure lsp.insertTable...incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT' and referes to the lines where in the Values

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this without having to use a temp table, possibly by using a Common Table Expression.  But if it's simpler to create a temp table, by all means do so.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table
(
    col6 int, -- change data types as appropriate
    col7 int,
    col8 int
    ...
)

INSERT INTO #temp_table
SELECT value6, value7 ... FROM Whatever -- whatever the query is.


INSERT INTO FinalTable
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8)
SELECT @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, col6, col7, col8
FROM   #temp_table
```

I'm not sure what you mean by saying you want to create the temp table "before the BEGIN".  Do you mean outside the stored procedure, by using the temp table as a table-valued parameter, or just that you want to create the temp table at the very beginning of the stored procedure?

ETA:  OK, if you're having trouble with the subqueries, it's probably because you aren't wrapping them in ( ).  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table
( fields )
VALUES 
(
  (select top 1 column1 from #temp_table) ,
  (select top 1 column2 from #temp_table)
  -- etc
)
```

Incidentally, the `BEGIN` and `END` in the stored procedure are not necessary.  You don't need to put that bit of code into a block (since it's not conditional or in a loop) so I'd either put the `BEGIN` back at the beginning, or take them both out.